# Python3.4 packing and format type with struct

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, binary, pack

I have a binary file which I am trying to recreate by writing data to a new file. The data in it should be stored as 32-bit (4-byte) twos- complement binary integers or as ASCII characters. The first 4 bytes should represent the integer 0, then the next 4 should be the integer 4, the next 4 should be the integer 180. The next 4 bytes I need to pack 014500 which represents `HourHourMinuteMinuteSecondSecond`. When `hexdumped`, it should appear as:

```
0000000 0000 0000 0004 0000 00b4 0000 ccf8 0001
```

With the last two columns representing the packed version of the last 4 bytes.  I cannot seem to replicate this.  I've tried packing as a string and as an integer (removing the leading zero for the latter).  I don't know what to do.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

I am on a 64 bit RHEL Linux box running python3.4.  My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

import struct

fout = open('brian', 'wb')
fout.write(struct.pack('I', 0))
fout.write(struct.pack('I', 4))
fout.write(struct.pack('I', 180)) 
fout.write(struct.pack('I', 14500))
# also tried:
# fout.write(struct.pack('4s', b'014500'))
```

Comment: Forget about the Python for a second. Can you break down the hexdump for me? I don't see how it matches your description of the fields. `0004 0000` decodes to 4 in neither big nor little endian. And I have no idea what `ccf8 0001` is. How is that a representation of 14520?

Comment: You ask good questions.  I am in over my head with the binary data, I really don't understand it.  From what I've read the results don't make sense to me either.  However they do match the hexdump of the originating binary file.

Comment: It's not a string as it wouldn't fit in 4 bytes. But, I still don't get how would *14520* yield *0001 ccf8*?

Comment: I had an error, the string should have been 14500.

Comment: John and Cristi, you both had the answer.  It was the 14500 -  turns out that was incorrect.  Turns out that was in the next 4 bytes.  What I should have been writing was 118008, which does come out to ccf8 0001.  Thanks so much for getting me straightened out.